# Hide and show footer with footer message In angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intel-xdk

I am trying to create an angular app in Intel XDK, I have 3 page scripts In index.html and have 3 separate footers.what I need is when I run each page  the footer and footer message will show and hide every 5 seconds

app.js

```
app.controller('main', function ($scope,$interval,$ionicModal,localStorageService,$http,$q,$templateCache) {
$scope.showFooter =true;
$scope.footer_message ='Powered By';
   $scope.checkConnection=function() {
            var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

            if(networkState == Connection.NONE){
                $scope.footer_message = "No Network Connection";

                return false;

            }else{
                $scope.footer_message = "Powered By";
                return true;
            }
        }

        $interval(function() {
            if($scope.showFooter)
            {
                $scope.showFooter =false;
            }
            else{
                $scope.showFooter =true;
            }
        },5000);
    });
```

index.html

I have 3 pages in index.html and 3 pages have separate 3 footers like

```
<div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced" style="background-color:#444444;">
                <div class="title">{{footer_message}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you looking for . But you can decide to show and hide footer based on "ng-show=showFooter"  .. if showFooter is true then footer will be visible otherwise not.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: I want to display message in footer in each page depend on network @voila

Comment: so whats the problem ? Look at answer given below by Punith .. isn't it what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I tried the example, you need to add ng-show to show and hide the footer on data change.

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

    app.controller('main', function ($scope,$interval) {
    $scope.showFooter =true;
    $scope.footer_message ='Powered By';    
        $interval(function() {
            if($scope.showFooter)
            {
                $scope.showFooter =false;
              console.log($scope.showFooter);
            }
            else{
                $scope.showFooter =true;
              console.log($scope.showFooter);
            }
        },5000);
    });
```

change the showFooter value based on the requirement.

```
<div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced" style="background-color:#444444;" ng-controller="main" ng-show="showFooter">
   <div class="title">{{footer_message}}</div>
</div>
```